# Comma separate values with same number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

### DATABASE STRUCTURE

**items**: `id, name`

**users**: `id, username`

**user_items**: `id, user_id, item_id`

I currently have a `count()` on `user_items` that shows the users with the most number of items:

```
john: 13
bill: 9
lily: 9
kent: 9
seth: 8
vick: 8
anna: 7
```

But I want to display it in this fashion:

```
13: john
 9: bill, lily, kent
 8: seth, vick
 7: anna
```

How can I achieve this with laravel's query system in blade?

Comment: could you use group_concat ? sorry I don't know laravel.

Comment: I would change the structure of your relationships. It seems that a user can have many items, but an item can have only one user. You don't need the pivot table `user_items`

Comment: Could you show the collection or array structure you get from db, before you displayed it in that former fashion >

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Controller get like this

```
$users = DB::table('user_items as ui')
    ->select('count',DB::raw("group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') as names"))
    ->from(DB::raw('(select count(*) as count,u.username as name from user_items ui  join users u on u.id=ui.user_id  group by u.id) a'))
    ->groupBy('count')
    ->orderBy('count','desc')
    ->get();

$data['users']=$users;

return View::make('hello',$data);
```

In view using blade

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <li>{{$user->count.':'. $user->names}}</li>
@endforeach
```

If you want users with no item to be displayed ,your query can be

```
$users = DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('count',DB::raw("group_concat(name SEPARATOR ', ') as names"))
            ->from(DB::raw('(select count(ui.item_id) as count,u.username as name from users u  left join user_items ui on u.id=ui.user_id  group by u.id) a'))
            ->groupBy('count')
            ->orderBy('count','desc')
            ->get();
```

To display names seperately add following code  before `$data['users']=$users;`

```
foreach($users as $user){
            $user->names=explode(', ',$user->names);
    }
```

And in blade you can

```
<ul>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <li>
            <span>{{$user->count}}:</span>

            @foreach($user->names as $index=>$name)
                <span><a href="#">{{$name}}</a> @if($index!=count($user->names)-1) ,@endif </span>
            @endforeach
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: This works great - but how can I iterate of the `$user->names` so I can wrap them with HTML anchor tags? Would this be another `@foreach` ?

Comment: `foreach($users as $user){
            $user->names=explode(', ',$user->names);
    }` and in view you can use second foreach loop to iterate over names

Comment: since `$user->names` is now a string, I'm assuming `explode()` separates it to an array? What's the proper blade formatting?

Comment: just to extend on this- I notice there isn't a particular sort order for the concatenated usernames. How can I define one so it orders by user id? Adding `order by` in the raw query does not seem to do anything.

Comment: maybe with little effort you can add `sort($user->names);` to foreach loop that explodes into array and then sort names.`$user->names=explode(', ',$user->names);
            sort($user->names);`

Answer (score 12):

Not sure about Laravel, but this is the pure MySQL version:

```
SELECT itemCount, GROUP_CONCAT(username)
FROM
(
   SELECT tblU.user_name, COUNT([DISTINCT] tblUI.item_id) AS itemCount
   FROM users AS tblU 
   INNER JOIN user_items AS tblUI ON tblU.id = tblUI.user_id
   GROUP BY tblU.user_name
) AS uic
GROUP BY itemCount
```

Note, DISTINCT is optional, hence the square brackets. Also, if you want the users without any items, you could make the JOIN a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest may be to process the DB result with PHP afterwards:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($db_result as $name => $item_count) {
    $result[$item_count][] = $name;
}
```

Then, to obtain your expected output, you might want to follow with an `implode()`:

```
foreach ($result as &$names) {
    $names = implode(', ', $names);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution's logic is same as Uueerdo, but improvement in readability, I also try using only single query (without nested), but not getting success.

```
select itemCount,group_concat(username) as userNames
from (
      SELECT username,COUNT(1) AS itemCount
      FROM users AS u INNER JOIN user_items AS ui 
                ON u.id =ui.user_id
      GROUP BY u.id
      ) as tempTab
group by itemCount
```

View sql in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83e06/10)