# Perform sub query in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I perform a sub query in eloquent?

I need to convert:

```
select * from(//complex sub query) as prds order by date desc
```

Comment: What query are you trying to convert? We're not psychics.

Comment: It's a massive query so didnt post it. I just need to know how to perform a select with a sub query.

Comment: I don't think you can use Eloquent for that, as Eloquent is connected to a model which in turn is connected to a single table in your database. You're better off using the DB facade.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31893645/4293929 may the query there help

Comment: Without seeing the query & knowing the details of your models, this question is unanswerable. However, there are a couple of points that might help: 1) you can use query builder expressions with Eloquent models, so `whereRaw` might help; and 2) if you can rewrite your big query so it returns a list of primary keys, you could use `whereIn` or a loop and `find` to build a list of Eloquent models.

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/a/24838367/784588

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to answer this without the specific tables, columns, etc.  But in general, the key to doing this kind of thing is that you can pass a function as the second parameter of `whereIn()` or `whereExists()`, and that will create a sub-query.  For example:

```
Products::whereExists(function ($query) {
   $query->select(DB::raw(1))->from('orders')
      ->whereRaw('orders.product_id = products.id');
})->get();
```

Or you can do something with whereIn() like this:

```
Products::whereIn('id', function ($query) use ($orderID) {
   $query->select('product_id')->from('orders')
      ->where('orders.id', $orderID);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

At first create subquery that you need

```
$subQuery = DB::table("some_table as s")
    ->select('s.name', DB::raw('count(s.id) as s_count'))
    ->join('other_table as o', 's.id', '=', 'o.val')
    ->where('o.values', $someVal)
    ->groupBy('s.name');
```

Than can create general query

```
$rows = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as sub"))->mergeBindings($subQuery)
    ->where('sub.name', $val)
    ->orderBy("sub.s_count", 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Also you can get count if need

```
$count = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as sub"))->mergeBindings($subQuery)
    ->where('sub.name', $val)
    ->count();
```